# Estimating a normal distribution from three order statistics

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, order-statistics

I am interested in predicting a normal distribution, but not sure if this is possible.

I do not have information on the mean or standard deviation. However, I know the range of values, let's say from 0 to 10, and I know the sample size, let's say 1000, and I also know that value 8.1 is the 50th highest value.

Is it possible in any way from this information to infer more about what the distribution looks like?

Comment: "However, I know the range of values" ... Do you mean by this that you know the highest and lowest values in the sample?

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I meant, they range from 0 to 10. So 0 is lowest and 10 is higher.

Comment: It sounds to me like you know three "order statistics" for your sample (the 1st, 50th and 1000th/last) and want to estimate (think that's more appropriate than "predict") the parameters of your distribution, is this correct? If not then feel free to revert my edit, better (clearer) titles generally attract answers!

Comment: Yes! that makes sense.

Comment: Do you really mean 50th, or do you mean 50th%, i.e., 500th (or 501)?

Comment: It would be the 50th, so 8.1 would be the 50th highest number out of 10, in a sample size of 1000.

Comment: Do you really know the distribution is Normal, or are you assuming that?  Depending on how you use it, assumption of Normality can be quite "dangerous".

Comment: I am just interested how a normal distribution with such parameters would look like. There is no danger here.

Comment: I would mostly be interested in a question like: If this was a normal distribution, what value does rank 10 have? And how does the distribution look like. I am mostly using R to graph my things, is it possible to estimate that using R?

Comment: How do you know the distribution is normal?

Comment: You can find methods in books about order statistics, for example https://www.amazon.com/Order-Statistics-Herbert-David/dp/0471389269/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1493315646&sr=1-1&keywords=order+statistics  chapter 8.

Comment: WTH is "50th highest number out of 10, in a sample size of 1000"? This didn't make anything clearer

Answer (score 11):

**Use maximum likelihood.**

Generally, suppose you have sorted array of order statistics $x_{[i]}$ for $i$ in a subset $\mathcal{I}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  Augment this vector to include $x_{[0]}=-\infty$ and $x_{[n+1]}=\infty$.  You are supposing the underlying distribution is $F_{\theta}$ with corresponding density $f_{\theta}$ and you wish to estimate $\theta$.  The likelihood of these order statistics, up to a factor that will not vary with $\theta$, is a product of the $f_\theta{x_{[i]}}$ (excluding $x_{[0]}$ and $x_{[n+1]}$, where necessarily $f=0$) times all the powers

$$\left(F_\theta(x_{[i_{j+1}]}) - F_\theta(x_{[i_j]})\right)^{i_{j+1}-i_j-1}$$

for $j$ from $1$ onward.  In the example of the question this would be

$$f_\theta(0)f_\theta(8.1)f_\theta(10)\ \left(F_\theta(8.1) - F_\theta(0)\right)^{949}\left(F_\theta(10) - F_\theta(8.1)\right)^{48}.$$

The rest is completely routine, provided you have at least as many order statistics as there are components of $\theta$: there typically will be a unique value of $\theta$ that minimizes this expression.  In the question, $\theta$ has two components and there are three order statistics, so all is fine.  The machinery of ML produces, in a standard way, estimated standard errors of the parameters, too.

---

To illustrate, the `R` code below estimates $\hat\mu=5.39794$ and $\hat\sigma=1.62553$ from the data in the question (namely, $(x_{[1]}, x_{[951]}, x_{[1000]}) = (0, 8.1, 10)$, with $n=1000$).  Then, as a quick visual check that the estimates are reasonable, it generates $1000$ datasets of size $n=1000$ from this Normal distribution, records the $1,951,$ and $1000$ order statistics (as given in the question), plots their histograms, and superimposes the observed order statistics on those histograms.  The fit is beautiful for orders $1$ and $951$ and reasonable for order $1000$ (the value of $10$ is around the twelfth percentile of this distribution--not too extreme).

[image: Figure of three histograms]

```
#
# Negative log likelihood.
#
Lambda <- function(theta) {
  mu <- theta[1]
  log.sigma <- theta[2]
  sigma <- exp(log.sigma)
  f <- dnorm(values, mu, sigma, log=TRUE)
  F <- log(diff(pnorm(c(-Inf, values, Inf), mu, sigma)))
  -(sum(f) + sum(F * (diff(c(0, orders, n+1))-1)))
}
#
# The data.
#
n <- 1000
orders <- c(1, 951, 1000)
values <- c(0, 8.1, 10)
#
# Compute the estimate.
#
theta.start <- c(mu=mean(range(values)), log.sigma=log(diff(range(values))/6))
fit <- nlm(Lambda, theta.start) # It converged.
theta.hat <- fit$estimate
mu.hat <- theta.hat[1]
sigma.hat <- exp(theta.hat[2])
#
# Check the quality of the estimate visually.
#
n.sim <- 1e3
n <- 1000
sim <- apply(matrix(rnorm(n.sim*n, mu.hat, sigma.hat), n), 2, sort)[orders, ]
par(mfrow=c(1, length(orders)))
invisible(
  sapply(1:length(orders), function(i) {
    hist(sim[i,], freq=FALSE, xlab="Value", main=paste("Order", orders[i]))
    abline(v=values[i], lwd=2, col="Red")
  })
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a sample of random numbers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{1000}$. What's know is $\min[x_i],\max[x_i]$ and 50th highest number A, which is 5th percentile in a sample 1000 long.

Given the information I'd go with $$\hat\mu=\frac{\min+\max}{2}=5$$, and $$\hat\sigma=\frac{A-\hat\mu}{1.65}=\frac{8.1-5}{1.65}\approx 1.9$$

The t-statistics 1.65 is derived from 5% one tail z-value. I bet that you can come up with a rigorous MLE procedure which would produce the same result

UPDATE

Here's another way of estimating the dispersion using @jth idea. The max and min [upper bounds](http://cnx.org/contents/i9MW2GRC@1/Maximum-of-a-Sequence-of-Gauss) are:
$$\max=\mu+\sigma(\sqrt{2\log n} +1)$$
Hence, $$\hat\sigma=\frac{\max-\min}{2(\sqrt{2\log n} +1)}=\frac{10}{2(\sqrt{2\log 1000}+1)}\approx 1.4$$

Comment: The max of $n$ Gaussians scales like $\sqrt{2 \log n}$. So you'd want to renormalize $\hat{\mu}$.

Comment: @jth Gaussian's a symmetric distribution, I can't see how max could have different dynamics than min. The center must be right in between min and max

Comment: This isn't a great solution. For the example data, we may compare this estimate to the Maximum Likelihood estimate by subtracting the log likelihoods and doubling them to produce their deviance.  The deviance is around $1300$, amounting to a *huge* error.  You have substantially overestimated the standard deviation.

Comment: @jth - no, you wouldn't, because the min and max are, in expectation, symmetric around the true mean.

Comment: My mistake, I thought the order statistics were of $|X_i|$. In which case it should be $\sqrt{2\log(2n)}$ also.

Comment: The new estimator of $\sigma$ completely ignores the third order statistic, using only the extremes of the data in its calculation.  As such we can expect it to have a substantially larger variance than other estimators that use all the data.  This would make it an *inadmissible* estimator. There are some nice estimators based on linear combinations of order statistics: they are especially useful with certain kinds of censored data.  For a brief description see, *e.g.*, http://www.itrcweb.org/gsmc-1/Content/GW%20Stats/5%20Methods%20in%20indiv%20Topics/5%207%20Nondetects.htm.

Comment: @whuber, the fact that it doesn't use all the data could be seen as an advantage :) it's economical

Comment: When you have only three data points, and two of them are as imprecise as possible (the extremes in this case), it's rarely a good idea to ignore the third and most reliable value!  The contrast really is stark in this example: the variances of the maximum and minimum are 1.5 orders of magnitude greater than the variance of the fiftieth largest value: compare the spreads in the three histograms in my answer.