# Estimating an underlying non-normal distribution from revealed statistics

Tags: estimation, density-function

Given only the minimum, maximum, mean, median, variance, and size of a population of real numbers, is it possible to write an expression for a probability density function that best represents the underlying distribution?

Specifically, I'm analyzing the heights of athletes in a particular sport, but I don't have access to every athlete's height. I do have the statistics mentioned above though, which have been computed from the entire population of relevant athletes.

Comment: Yes, provided you are willing to limit that distribution to a family with a small number of parameters.  Your question is similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207403, where a Normal distribution is fitted to three quantiles (the min, max, median, and size give you information about three quantiles).  The mean can be expressed as a linear combination of quantiles, allowing you (in principle) to extend the approaches suggested in that thread, as well as to extend the Normal family to include some kind of skewed distributions. The variance similarly might be accommodated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious best-guess probability distribution given these specific summary statistics. I should add that any choice will also likely depend on your prior beliefs about how the distribution should be shaped.

The obvious choices would be a normal distribution (if the mean and median are very close) or a skew-normal distribution (if the difference between the mean and median is important). The max and min for a given n could act a cross-check on model by comparing them with the relevant order statistics. If these are professional athletes, you are effectively modeling the convolution of the right-tail of a distribution of ability with a distribution of interest, and some more complicated shape is likely to work better.

Finally, once you have a distribution, be circumspect in making inferences about aspects of the distribution (higher moments, further out tails) that did not go into your fit.