# Generate given percentile (or data) from n, mean, median, standard deviation, p1, p25, p50, p75, p99?

Tags: stata, quantiles, skew-normal-distribution

I apologize if this should be asked elsewhere.

I have the following information:

[image]

Where N=1808

I am trying to calculate a given percentile (in this case p99.723), or ideally, if possible, generate data from this information. Unfortuneately, I do not have access to any further data, as this information is from a Journal article.

I'm running into trouble due to the extreme skewness of the distribution. Given the above information, I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to generate data from this information?
2. If not (which I'm assuming I cannot), can I calculate the value for a given percentile (p99.723)?
3. How can one do this? (I'm currently using Stata, but have access to Excel and am willing to do this by hand as well if needed).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No - you have to make assumptions about the distributions and then try to shape them around the data.   For example, at least $19$ institutions sent nothing in the year, and many more sent nothing on some days.  You might try to derive that there could have been about $\frac{508.75\times 1808}{2580}\approx 356.5$ days in the year which is slightly strange, and might suggest day-of-the-week seasonality

Comment: @Henry, I'm assuming that your "no" response is to both questions (e.g. generate data or the p99.723 values), is that correct?

Also, while I'd prefer to be as precise as possible, I am okay with making assumptions as this informtion would be used to inform further research questions, rather than inform the findings of research itself.

Comment: Sure you can estimate percentiles from this information: but as @Henry points out, those estimates require making assumptions.  Your estimates of the higher percentiles will be *extremely* sensitive to those assumptions!

Comment: @whuber, How can I go about estimating the percentiles from this?

Comment: You assume a distribution family, fit a distribution, and use the percentiles of that distribution.  I give an example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276322/919 based on three percentiles.  A mixture of percentiles and moment-based statistics is difficult to handle, because the likelihood is intractable, but one could use approximate methods to fit a distribution.  The critical issue concerns your distributional assumption, because (for extreme percentiles) the answers depend even more on that than they do on the data!

Comment: @whuber, for your method, would a negative exponential distribution family seem appropriate to you? I apologize for the elementary nature of this inquiry, my stats skills are quite rusty.

Comment: It's impossible to tell, because you just can't accurately characterize the top quartile of the distribution, or even its general shape, from just the 75th and 99th percentiles.  If you were to fit a negative exponential and find that it agrees well with all the percentiles, that would be of interest.

Comment: Why are you interested in the 99.723 percentile?